# Python - Solve some mathematical problems in a list filled with random elements

Tags: python, list

Task: In a list filled with random numbers you need to count:

1. A sum of negative numbers
2. A sum of even numbers
3. A sum of odd numbers
4. A product of elements with indexes that multiple 3
5. A product of elements between min and max element
6. A sum of elements, which located between first and last element

I can't figure out how to solve last two issues

The code I have so far:

```
import random

size = int(input('Enter the size of a list: '))
begin = int(input('Enter the beginning of a list: '))
end = int(input('Enter the end of a list: '))

my_list = list()
for i in range(size):
    my_list.append(random.randint(begin, end))

for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    print(f'{my_list[i]}[{i}]', end=' ')
print()

mul = 1
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3):
    print(f'{mul} * {my_list[i]}[{i}] = ', end=' ')
    mul *= my_list[i]
    print(mul)

sum_list = [0] * 3

for item in my_list:
    if item < 0:
        sum_list[0] += item
    if item % 2 == 0:
        sum_list[1] += item
    if item % 2 != 0:
        sum_list[2] += item

print(f'Sum negative: {sum_list[0]}')
print(f'Sum even: {sum_list[1]}')
print(f'Sum odd: {sum_list[2]}')
print(f'Mul even 3 index: {mul}')
```

Comment: Hint: `min`, `max`, and `sort` may be of use here

Comment: What does „ elements between min and max element“ actually mean? The elements *positioned* between the smallest and largest elements? The elements *excluding* the smallest and largest elements?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A product of elements between min and max element

For this task, you can use .sort() method of the "list" object to sort it in-place then use list indexes to exclude the first and last item (min and max because it is sorted) and then use math.prod to calculate the product of rest

```
import math
my_list.sort()
math.prod(my_list[1:-1]) if len(my_list) > 2 else 0
```

> A sum of elements, which located between the first and last element

Use list indexes to get the remaining elements and sum() them

```
sum(my_list[1:-1]) if len(my_list) > 2 else 0 # we need to check if list is long enough
```

Comment: I guess one can get lost in the semantics here. By product of elements between the min and max, I would have dropped the min() and the max() and summed up all the numbers that were left in the array.

Comment: Yeah I've misread the task, fixed

Comment: the thing is I am not sure whether you need to get the products of the min() and max() or the numbers specifically in between the min() and the max(). I guess that's for OP to decide?

Comment: The two blocks compute exactly the same since the first leaves the list in sorted order.